# Is it possible to change the philosophical orientation of judicial matters in small social structures?

Tags: society, politics, law

I have a question about social structures in modern times.

Why is it that people tend to build the strictest rules in small groups like forums and social media communities, even though in reality they tend to desire and claim even more and more degrees of freedom?

Why do people seem to care so much about stupidities like sets of 'relevance' and 'specificity' rules as if it had in fact some sort of essential, fundamental or deeper meaning other than just showing shortness of mind while trying (and failing) to keep high quality standards of social interaction? Why said people would probably freak out if they had to live in a society where similar sets of rules were applied to every day life?

In your philosophical or sociological opinion, is there any deeper diference between smaller cybergroups and reality macro groups to justify this apparent incongruence of judicial orientation? Perhaps it's just an artificial tool that theoretically no one really believes in but that experience taught to be an effective way to keep the order? or do you think this kind of people just got fooled by their egos to truly believe that there is something utterly important going on in said small environment besides a bunch of random people on the internet exchanging information?

I was thinking about building a society based on anarchy where there were no moderation, thus no space for show-off and despotic arrogance from simple-mided individuals that somehow got in charge of some random socially unrelevant cyber microgroup, got used to and fond of random dubious legislative patterns and are eager to apply them and play judge.

What do you people think? Is it even possible or against human nature? Perhaps I should create a different species/race as well?

Comment: Ironically, by rules you are asking about this question does not belong in WB stack. It would probably be better fit in philosophy, psychology or politics. Only last paragraph counts as WB and likely is too broad. For the record: I did not vote to close.

Comment: @Miech If you feel a question is off topic or too broad you should either edit it or VTC.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please note that while the community does accept and respond to societal questions concerning law and order, this feels more like a rant being hammered into a shape to resemble a question. Also, questions asking, "What do you people think?" are universally considered _primarily opinion-based_. The StackExchange is a collection of Q&A sites, not an open forum for general discussion on a topic. If you haven't already, feel free to take the [tour]. This question is likely to be put on hold until an [edit] is made to bring it in line with the community expectations.

Comment: I rest my case, LOL

Comment: 'Despotic arrogance' is often in the eye of the beholder. If my train schedule says a train arrives at 10:05, is it despotic arrogance if the operator encourages running the trains on time? Or is it despotic arrogance if the train crew ignores the timetable and runs when they wish? Is it despotic arrogance if I trust the published timetable?

Comment: @sphennings Nah. I approve the message. Private censorship is a very serious issue and legislation needs curb it sooner or later.

Comment: @Miech, private censorship is a contradiction in terms. A message board like this means that **somebody** is providing software and hardware for people to use, free of **direct** fees. In the offline world, there are different rules regarding free speech and censorship on a public street and in a private home. If the home owner throws an obnoxious visitor out, that's not censorship ...

Comment: @J.Henrique, read this explanation: https://xkcd.com/1357/

Comment: @o.m. Message board or forum is not a private space. The moment it goes live it becomes public space. Email conversation between 2 people may be private. SMS talk, or direct chat may be private. Forum is not and because of that, should be held to same standard as public space.

Comment: @Miech, **no**. It is a private space organized by either some volunteers or a *company* who invite others in to participate. That doesn't make it public in the same way a public street is public. There is a Stack Exchange, Inc.which controls this site.

Comment: @o.m. Obviously it's not private as speaking inside your house. Obviously it's not public as street speech either. There are categories between these extremes, you know? if "That doesn't make it public in the same way a public street is public" then that doesn't make it private in the same way a private home is private. This is so basic.

Comment: @o.m. As a general rule, home is not open to thousands (or millions for particularly successful sites) and opinions spoken in home are not influencing said thousands (or millions). As such, fora, message boards, facebook groups, facebook as a whole, youtube, etc. are not private. Due to their outreach those are public places and should be treated as such. Criminal posts should be handled as such and handed over to police and judiciary, rest is censorship and political control on scale most tyrannical regimes couldn't even dream of.

Comment: @Miech , well put. And good use of latin plural btw.

Comment: I still haven't decided if this @Frostfyre person doesn't get irony or what. After reading what I wrote, the guy invites me to take 'tours' and to 'edit' the question in order to be 'legal' under their cyberkingdom code of law. Just delete it, ban me or whatever, fellow. There would be more dignity in it and that's what we are all expecting you to do to rebels and traitors of the e-fiefdom.

Comment: I understand irony. However, being among the older and higher rep users, it falls to us to ensure the site remains clean and healthy, as well as abiding by the decisions we as a community generate. The actions you specify can only be done by the lurking diamond moderators, but they typically rely on the high-rep users to manage the community.